# Can someone provide a transliteration of Sri Lankan script following the western Pali standard?

Tags: pali-language, scripture

Sadly, Indo-Germanic languages aren't well transliterated following international standards (which are far from purposes, aside of productivity and cutting down to lowest).

The romanization of Pali and Sanskrit romanization often follow a totally different standard -- it's good if Sri Lankan could follow more language conservation standards.

Maybe someone likes to help with an alphabet list that gives Pali in Sri Lankan script -- a transliteration following the international standards for Pali-to-Roman and also international romanization of Sri Lanka script -- that western could also do an effort to have no hindrances.

Be aware that SE-Asian isn't well supported by Google Translate, and so you can make much merits in Dhamma helping here personally to answer.

There is a development by Brahman Vinodh: 
http://aksharamukha.appspot.com/converter

Not sure how well it works for Sri Lankan script and Pali, since the Developer heads much toward Sanskrit and worldly standards -- I at least observe in other languages that it does not fail for Buddha-Dhamma yet -- but surely also happy to receive generosity for the good parts of the Undertaking.

Not sure in how much Sri Lankan script deals well with special characters for loan words from Sanskrit and Pali aside the native language script.

*[Note that this is not given for trade, exchange and stacks by for liberation from this bond]*

Comment: I'm sorry but questions which are purely about language -- e.g. questions about Pali, Sanskrit, Sinhalese, Chinese, Thai, etc. (and not about Buddhism) -- have been considered off-topic in the past -- see for example [Are questions about Sanskrit off-topic?](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2036/254) and the comments under [this answer](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1783/254).

Comment: I won't contradict you, I don't know, but are you sure that Google Translate doesn't transliterate Sinhalese? If I go to https://translate.google.com/ and paste in `යම්පිච්ඡං න ලභති තම්පි දුක්ඛං` then it displays (on the left-hand side) `yampicchaṁ na labhati tampi dukkhaṁ` which looks like the usual Pali romanization.

Comment: google, tools, dictionaryies ... are developed by christians and muslimes. Transliteration learned and shared, as seeing all the times, is different. and not really knowing why "interest" to point you folks anything out... stay ignorant & arrogant...

Comment: Brahma google worshipper... useless, bond to Mara... delete it and let them google...

Comment: @SamanaJohann Translating word to word won't help to understand the real dhamma. What I meant by real dhamma is the core of buddhism not to label it mahayana or theravada. 
What you need to do is discuss dhamma with someone who has understand dhamma, who does have the right view but not with someone who claims he represents mahayana or something similar to that. Because that says he doesn't know the real dhamma. So what need to do is start discussions (face to face or live calls). After you also get the right view, you may read and align the meaning to the right view.

Answer (score 1):

Google translate Singhala

[image]

If you type Pali you get the Romanised version below the text.

[image]

Also, this might be helpful: [Sinhala script - Use for the Pali language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinhala_script#Use_for_the_Pali_language)

Comment: It does not seem as if Nyom understands the question, not ever thought much anout proper tranliteration into latin in pali standard... merely just to keep ones avatar online and use free traded to not lose something while making own ads-on for land- and recources sales... right? Please correct if not.

Comment: The link to wiki seems to be well (at least for those wishing to use Pali and the Dhamma for worlds bounds) and maybe he likes to remove the uncommented google nonsens. Pali and Sri Lanken spelled equal or differently using same script? Sure he will be to busy to give some of his time and effort with danger to gain to less for wealthy at death.